# Archlinux ARM Rasperry Pi decryption fail

Tags: keyboard, login, cryptsetup, mkinitcpio

I have created an encrypted Archlinux partition on my SD card, but currently I am unable to decrypt it. I am using the key "Xö&(4n=%YF3Ü!BN" which includes german letters. So for this I have included to /etc/mkinitcpio.conf:

```
HOOKS="[...] keyboard keymap consolefont encrypt [...]"
```

In /etc/vconsole.conf I have added

```
KEYMAP=de-latin1
FONT=lat9w-16
```

And in /boot/cmdline.txt I have added:

```
vconsole.keymap=de-latin1 vconsole.font=lat9w-16
```

But I am still unable to decrypt it and I just do not know how to solve this.

I am looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: Not really answer to the question, but next time consider using longer pass-phrase and hash it to get a key. Security is the same and it will be more user friendly.

Comment: As for the question: how (read from where) have you used the key when you created the encrypted partition? The problem might be in the fact, that in one place the characters are UTF encoded while in the other one ISO-8859-1 is used. Typically this would happen if you do one from the X environment and the other on console (unless you make sure the encodings match).

Comment: I have setup this with a keyboard attched to the Pi. Tha main problems are the German letters: ü, ö and ä and maybe ß. The rest keyboard letters should work.

Comment: It's not a question of the letters being printed out correctly or being able to enter them at all. It is what bytes are fed to the encryption engine that matters. Your key is represented as (hexadecimal) `58 f6 26 28 34 6e 3d 25 59 46 33 dc 21 42 4e` in Latin1 and as `58 c3 b6 26 28 34 6e 3d 25 59 46 33 c3 9c 21 42 4e` in UTF-8.

Comment: Is there a possibility to print out the hex values of my keys at the time of enetering the needed passphrase? As it works correctly as sson as I login.

Comment: There are several utilities for that, `hexdump` or `xxd` being two of those.

Comment: yes, but is it possibly to do this at the booting time, so that when I get asked to enter my decryption key. As later it works correctly e.g. when i use luksOpen.

Comment: In that case your question is missing some important information - about what exactly works and what doesn't. What exactly might help is comparing environment (e.g. output of `env`) from points where it works and where it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

I think your `KEYMAP` declaration is wrong. I believe it should be like this:

```
KEYMAP=de-latin1
```

Comment: Sry, it was just a typing mistake here in the forum